# Images overlapping in chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I am using a free template to build a website. The template is great. But I realize that images are overlapping in chrome browser.

It should look like this;

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/IyWL8.jpg]

but the actual situation is;

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/DPRmE.jpg]

I think it is a js issue but I don't know how to solve it. How could I manage to make it working in chrome too?

Edit: Sorry to forget adding codes

```html
<div class="container page-content">

   <!-- #options -->
   <div id="container" class="row portfolio-grid-textblock">
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 element wordpress ui-design" data-symbol="Mg" data-category="wordpress">
     <a href="portfolio-item-style2.html">
     <div class="image-link">
      <img alt="Reponsive Style" src="img/PortfolioImg/astrolojiler-home.jpg"/>
     </div>
     <div class="portfolio-texbox">
      <h5>ASTROLOJİLER</h5>
      <p>
       Burç yorumları, yükselen burçlar, çin astrolojisi, hint astrolojisi...
      </p>
     </div>
     </a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 element actinoid bootstrap" data-symbol="U" data-category="actinoid">
     <a href="portfolio-item-style2.html">
     <div class="image-link">
      <img alt="Reponsive Style" src="img/PortfolioImg/numeroloji-home.jpg"/>
     </div>
     <div class="portfolio-texbox">
      <h5>NÜMEROLOJİ</h5>
      <p>
       Sayı bilimi, aşk uyumu ve harflere karşılık gelen rakamlar...
      </p>
     </div>
     </a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 element lanthanoid bootstrap" data-symbol="Gd" data-category="lanthanoid">
     <a href="portfolio-item-style2.html">
     <div class="image-link">
      <img alt="Reponsive Style" src="img/PortfolioImg/fallar-home.jpg"/>
     </div>
     <div class="portfolio-texbox">
      <h5>FALLAR</h5>
      <p>
       Kahve falı, tarot falı, el falı, renk falı, zar falı, çiçek falı, niyet falı ve daha birçok fal...
      </p>
     </div>
     </a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 element wordpress ui-design" data-symbol="Y" data-category="wordpress">
     <a href="portfolio-item-style2.html">
     <div class="image-link">
     <a href="portfolio-item-style2.html">
     <div class="image-link">
      <img alt="Reponsive Style" src="img/PortfolioImg/biyoritim-home.jpg"/>
     </div>
     <div class="portfolio-texbox">
      <h5>BİYORİTİM</h5>
      <p>
       Biyoritim değerlerinizi günlük olarak görmek için buraya tıklayın...
      </p>
     </div>
     </a> 
     </div>
     
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 element" data-symbol="B" data-category="ui-design">
     <a href="portfolio-item-style2.html">
     <div class="image-link">
      <img alt="Reponsive Style" src="img/PortfolioImg/ruya-tabirleri-home.jpg"/>
     </div>
     <div class="portfolio-texbox">
      <h5>RÜYA TABİRLERİ</h5>
      <p>
       Rüyanızda gördüğünüz şeyler ne anlama geliyor öğrenmek için tıklayın...
      </p>
     </div>
     </a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 element wordpress ui-design" data-symbol="Fe" data-category="wordpress">
     <a href="portfolio-item-style2.html">
     <div class="image-link">
      <img alt="Reponsive Style" src="img/PortfolioImg/karakter-analizi-home.jpg"/>
     </div>
     <div class="portfolio-texbox">
      <h5>KARAKTER ANALİZİ</h5>
      <p>
       Nasıl bir karakteriniz var? Karakterinizi belirleyen etkenler nelerdir?...
      </p>
     </div>
     </a>
    </div>
   </div><script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
<!-- ae-yeni-alt -->
<ins class="adsbygoogle"
     style="display:block"
     data-ad-client="ca-pub-2108313464701654"
     data-ad-slot="9514974529"
     data-ad-format="auto"></ins>
<script>
(adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
</script>
  </div>
  
  <!-- Dotted line between footer -->
  <hr class='dotted'/>
  <footer class="below-footer">
  <div class="container ">
   <div class="pull-right smalllogo">
    <div>
     <!--<a href="http://themifycloud.com/downloads/skyway-responsive-html5-template/"><i class="fa fa-dot-circle-o"></i> SkyWay</a>-->
    </div>
   </div>
   <a id="scrolltotop" href="#" class="btn btn-default btn-sm"><i class="fa fa-angle-up fa-2x"></i></a>
   <p>
    &copy; 2011-2015 AstroEnerji.com &nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="http://www.astroenerji.com" class="primary-color">Kullanım Koşulları</a>&nbsp; |&nbsp; <a href="http://www.astroenerji.com" class="primary-color">Gizlilik Bildirimi</a>
   </p>
  </div>
  </footer>
  <!-- End of footer -->
 </div>
</div>
</div>
<!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript
    ================================================== -->
<!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.easing.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.prettyPhoto.js"></script>
<script src="vendor/isotope/jquery.isotope.min.js"></script>
<script src="vendor/isotope/js/fake-element.js"></script>
<script src="js/site.js"></script>
```

Comment: We need to see your code.

Comment: How can you possibly ask for coding help, without providing the code to help with?  You gave us a jpg.  By what you've given us, my suggestion would be to use the top image and not the bottom.  But if you want actual code help, you need to provide CODE.

Comment: Read up on Images Loaded. It could be your theme uses a masonry style script and needs to measure the height of those divs that are stacking on top of each other. If that's the case Images Loaded would be what you need.

Answer (score 0):

You've got something screwy going on in the 4th box -- the one with data-symbol="Y"

```
<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 element wordpress ui-design" data-symbol="Y" data-category="wordpress">
    =>   <a href="portfolio-item-style2.html">
    =>   <div class="image-link">**
       <a href="portfolio-item-style2.html">
       <div class="image-link">
          <img alt="Reponsive Style" src="img/PortfolioImg/biyoritim-home.jpg"/>
       </div>
       <div class="portfolio-texbox">
          <h5>BİYORİTİM</h5>
          <p>Biyoritim değerlerinizi günlük olarak görmek için buraya tıklayın...</p>
       </div>
       </a> 
        </div>
 **extra div here => </div>
```

If you take out the two lines that I put a => in front of, that should fix it.

I think you also have an extra  tag at the end of that block. Remove that also.

If that doesn't fix it then we'll need to see the issue on a full html page, on bootply, jsfiddle, or your server, etc.

Comment: thanks for the answer, but it did not solve the problem. the original page of this script is below; http://www.themifycloud.com/demos/templates/skyway/portfolio-grid-col-3-style1.html

Comment: Giving me the link to the original template doesn't help because the problem is not there. The problem is on your website. I suspect that when you changed out the images and/or the text, something got messed up. I'd be happy to troubleshoot the actual page on your actual website if you'd like to provide that link

Comment: Sorry for the late answer, the link to my site is http://www.garantimaclar.com/astro/5/portfolio-grid-col-3-style1.html